# Can I use node.js npm and socket.io on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, node.js, cloud, socket.io

Can I use node.js npm and socket.io on google app engine

or suggest some low-cost or free solution on cloud that provide a socket.io module becouse I need this for realtime omunication with server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Node support on Google App Engine is available through what Google calls "The App Engine flexible environment". Where your code is running in a docker container hosted by Google. This is in contrast to "The App Engine standard environment" where your code is running in some soft of custom built container. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs). Documentation for Node on Google App Engine can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/).

**NOTE:** The flexible environment is currently in beta! And according to Google [not recommended](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) for production use.

Web sockets can be used on Google App Engine. However according to [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/websockets) for using websockets on Google App Engine; encrypted websockets are currently not supported.

For alternative hosting: The Node wiki maintains a list of hosting providers; [old wiki(but somewhat maintained)](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting), [new wiki](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Node-Hosting). On these wiki pages you can find different types of both free and paid plans for Node hosting.

Comment: As of june 2016, node is a supported language on Google Apps
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/

Comment: Node.js is very much supported now as a part of [Google AppEngine Flexible Env.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/). You could simply bring socket.io package and get the instance rolling. Pretty straight forward now.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to configure a [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/) instance to run a node application.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJs is now suppprted on Google App Engine, as well as other languages.
Just follow:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world